# Is BS(1, 2) a knot group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, combinatorial-group-theory

Is the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1, 2)$ a knot group ($\pi_1$ of a knot complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$)?

It has the presentation $\langle a, b\hspace{1mm}| \hspace{1mm}aba^{-1} = b^2\rangle $.

Comment: Is there any reason you think it should/should not be a knot group? (Or alternatively: why do you want to know? What is the context for the problem?)

Comment: It is not even a 3-manifold group.

Comment: As this has a vote to reopen, I want to clarify my close vote: if you know certain well-known things about Baumslag-Solitar groups and about not groups, this question is basically trivial. But I don't know if the OP knows these things, because no context is given ..